# MVC form combination of object in Map key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, thymeleaf

The name is not very good. I am sending from a controller a

```
Map<Object1,Object2> data
```

into a form in html.

I use the same object to get the data on submit.

Until now the Object1 was a String but now it has to change to an Object of 2 variables.

In the table of the form i was placing

```
th:name="${data.key}"
```

and the submit was working correctly when i was using String.

Now after the change submit tries to set Object1 but it finds the string representation of it.

What should i change in html so the form can submit normally a Map

Comment: We need more supporting code to give you a proper answer. Is `th:name="${data.key}"` somewhere within a loop of the map? Is data's value also used on the same input as the name value you show? How was your html structured before that kept a map on submission?

Comment: i have fixed it overidding the toString function of Object1 and returning the Map to <string,object2>

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed it overidding the `toString` function of Object1 and returning the Map to

```
<string,object2>
```